# How can I set the plotly-python's 'dropdown' menus look like in Dash?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

The dropdown menus in plotly-python consist of "buttons", not like in Dash. When I have many items to select(says 60), that will bother me. How can I do it?

Comment: I understand and I can follow your issue as experienced plotly / dash developer. You may post this issue inside plotly / dash community as chris is very open for new feature requests. Additionally, the community is very strong.

At the moment I wasn't able to bring up a fix for your issue.